# PHP PDO - Close statement - Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I close a statement using PDO? If I check the general MySQL log I never encounter the closing command. (command_type: Close stmt).

As of now MySQL throws "Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements" after a few of these queries.

A weird thing is that PDO prepares the query, even if there is nothing to prepare. Why not just execute the query (command_type: Execute)?

Snippet

```
// Executes a SQL query and returns the PDO statement
$statement = $pdo->query(sprintf('CALL TEST_PROCEDURE(%s)', implode(',', $parameters)));

// Retrieve the result of the query
$result = current($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

$statement = null;
```

The general log

```
select * from mysql.general_log where argument like "%call%" \G;
...
  event_time: 2016-09-01 10:34:40
   user_host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
   thread_id: 4111
   server_id: 0
command_type: Prepare
    argument: CALL TEST_PROCEDURE(234,'989',1,'3353' ....)
*************************** 2. row ***************************
command_type: Execute
    argument: CALL TEST_PROCEDURE(234,'989',1,'3353' ....)
```

Comment: PDO doesn't prepare anything when no prepare() method is used. I'd say it's something with mysql log

Comment: Some thoughts: Really, the PDO 'query()' function is for things that return results i.e. `SELECT`s. For everything else `exec()` ([executes an SQL statement in a single function call](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)) should be used. So, when the  `query()` function is used for a 'call' then something has to convert it into an 'exec()' statement. PDO or the database engine. Why you are getting prepared statements will need more searching.

Comment: @RyanVincent The MySQL procedure is returning, hence the query method and not exec.

Comment: @user634545 by the way, can you try exec() instead of query()? Just in case.

Comment: Now I am confused. I thought a  mysql procedure cannot return a value as that is what functions are for? `Out parameters` can be used to return values from procedures. Which is another, separate, issue with PDO...

Comment: @RyanVincent It's possible, $result = current($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)); returns the last selection in the TEST_PROCEDURE procedure

Comment: I learn something new every day. Thanks :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense The exec method results in "command_type: Query", so that is good. But I still need the returned value of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the connection explicitly with calling `$statement->closeCursor();`

Comment: I have tried closeCursor as well, did no differens.

Comment: `$statement = null;` is doing effectively the same. this question you are trying to raise some reputation points on is not as silly as you think.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Wow, I started to miss your valuable comments. :)